# SailsJS: How do I set attributes to NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I noticed that if I don't POST an attribute from the REST API that it just gets set to NULL. How do I enforce NOT NULL in my Sails.js model?

Comment: Do you try defaultsTo in your model ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that? I'm very new to sailsjs.

Comment: If I understand your problem you have null in your database. You can set a default value in your model declaration : http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Attributes.html . In your class : defaultsTo: '111-222-3333'

Comment: I understand that you can set a default value you now. But, what I want is to enforce a value, not just default to some value. Usually I would write code in the route handler that would check and validate the fields from the request and if anything is missing, I would give an error. Is there a way to do this in sailsjs? Better yet, I noticed a `required` property for the `primaryKey` property; can I use `required` to enforce a attribute?

Comment: Can you give me an exemple ? What you wanna do.

Answer (score 4):

You want to set `required:true`

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#validations

```
attributes: {
  username: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to set `null` as false from Models

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the attribute to be required and want replace default `null` with something else you can use `defaultsTo` as well:

```
attributes: {
  status: {
    type: 'string',
    defaultsTo: 'pending'
  }
}
```